# apache portable runtime binary for windows?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

from http://apr.apache.org , apr only available in source format. any third party side we can get apr pre-compiled ready so that i can use with tomcat6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are windows binaries downloadable for Tomcat Native ... see http://www.apache.org/dist/tomcat/tomcat-connectors/native/

This doesn't help if you want to use the latest version of the apr, but they work for me.

Comment: may i know beside putting tcnative-1.dll file, is there require to put openssl.exe in the same path also ?

Comment: Yes, by default when APR is enabled it will use OpenSSL and require openssl on the path. I believe you can switch this off in the APR configuration if you want, e.g. <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="off" />

Comment: `<Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on" />` is in %CATALINA_HOME%\conf\server.xml